# what libraries should I include to finally use the selendroid ? I really need a server?

Tags: java, selendroid

I'm reading some tutorials on the internet, but each of them says something different from others ...

Some say necessary to include all the .jar within the project : Selendroid , Selenium and WebDriver .

Elsewhere say it is only necessary to include the selendroid the project.

Some tutorials teach run the server before running the application, but did not understand.

what should i do?

Since I go first run the application in the emulator and then wheel it right into the cellphone .

My idea is to press a button on the form and then the program will be in charge of opening the browser and navigate alone.

Any good tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this link [Beginning with Selendroid](http://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selendroid.html) to learn basics of selendroid and how to start with it. All your doubts should get cleared with the help of this link.

Comment: But in this tutorial it teaches to perform tests on an APK already existing code and ready .

I seek a tutorial that teaches develop the code to access web page and show me what procedures ... such as which libraries that need to be added and how the server should be started.

Comment: Can't you develop simple code which takes an input and on pressing button, prints it in a textview and generate an apk! And this tutorial clearly shows what all libraries you need and how to start a server! If you want readymade code, go for the test-apk source code here https://github.com/selendroid/selendroid/tree/master/selendroid-test-app understand its flow and implement it in your project and then write testcases!